# Problem fetching json file in js for a website

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm trying to put some images from a json file into a websitepage as a carousel, but it keeps coming up with an error saying the json file can't be fetched.

i use example code from my uni lectures that comes with a link to example images, and that works. when i try to change the fetch line to fetch('assets/carouselImages.json) , it gives me errors. I am using vscode for this project.

here is the carousel.js:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  
  // Images container
  var images = document.getElementById('carouselImages');
  
  // Image caption
  var caption = document.getElementById('carouselCaption');
  
  // Previous image button
  var prev = document.getElementById('carouselPrev');
  
  // Next image button
  var next = document.getElementById('carouselNext');
  
  fetch("assets/carouselImages.json")
  
  // Do something with the response...
  .then(function(res) {
  
    // Get the JSON representation of the response object then...
    res.json().then(function(json) {
  
      // Loop over each object in our JSON object (array)...
      json.forEach(function(el, i) {
  
        // Create a new image element...
        var image = document.createElement('img');
  
        // Set some attributes...
        image.setAttribute('src', el.url);        // The url of the image
        image.setAttribute('alt', el.caption);    // The alternative text
        image.setAttribute('title', el.caption);  // The tooltip
  
        // Append this image to our carouselImages element
        images.appendChild(image);
      });
      
      // Once our images are all loaded in, set up our carousel...
      // We pass our JSON object (array) to this function
      setupCarousel(json);
    });
  });
  
  
  /* ----------------------------------
    A function to set up our carousel
  ---------------------------------- */
  
  // Carousel setup function (called from inside our fetch callback above)
  // This function accepts the JSON object (array) of images as an argument
  function setupCarousel(json) {
    
    /* -------------------------------------------
      Set some variables to keep track of things
    ------------------------------------------- */
  
    // Number of children in your carouselImages element
    var imageCount = images.childElementCount;
  
    // Current image in view
    var currentImage = 1;
  
    // Width of your images (could be calculated from clientWidth)
    // var imageWidth = images.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].clientWidth;
    var imageWidth = 500;
    
    /* ----------------------------------------
      Set some event listeners on our buttons
    ---------------------------------------- */
  
    // Previous button
    // Calls an anonymous function when the prev button is clicked
    prev.addEventListener('click', function() {
  
      // If the image in view is not the first image...
      if(currentImage != 1) {
  
        // Decrement the current image reference
        --currentImage;
  
        // Move the previous image into view using the left property
        images.style.left = imageWidth - (currentImage * imageWidth) + 'px';
      }
      
      // Update our caption
      caption.innerText = json[currentImage - 1].caption;
    });
  
    // Next button
    // Calls an anonymous function when the next button is clicked
    next.addEventListener('click', function() {
  
      // If the image in view is not the last image...
      if(currentImage != imageCount) {
  
        // Increment the current image reference
        ++currentImage;
  
        // Move the next image into view using the left property
        images.style.left = imageWidth - (currentImage * imageWidth) + 'px';
      }
      
      // Update our caption
      caption.innerText = json[currentImage - 1].caption;
    });
    
    // Update our caption
    caption.innerText = json[currentImage - 1].caption;
  }
  
  // The end of our DOMContentLoaded callback function
  });
```

and the carouselImages.json file:

```
[
    {
      "url": "images/one.jpg",
      "caption": "one"
    },
    {
      "url": "images/two.jpg",
      "caption": "two"
    },
    {
      "url": "images/three.jpg",
      "caption": "three"
    },
    {
      "url": "images/four.jpg",
      "caption": "four"
    },
    {
      "url": "images/five.jpg",
      "caption": "five"
    },
    {
      "url": "images/six.jpg",
      "caption": "six"
    },
    {
      "url": "images/seven.jpg",
      "caption": "seven"
    },
    {
      "url": "images/eight.jpg",
      "caption": "eight"
    },
    {
      "url": "images/nine.jpg",
      "caption": "nine"
    }
  ]
```

the carousel.js is saved in a folder called js, and the carouselImages.json is saved in a folder called assets. any help would be appreciated! :)

Comment: URLs are relative to the HTML page's location, not the JS file.

Comment: *"an error saying the json file can't be fetched"* - Why can't it?  In the browser's debugging tools, what exact and complete information is shown on the browser's development console and in the network tab for the AJAX request?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.